# Time scale for cAMP-dependent pathway cascades

Tags: gene-expression, cell-signaling, receptor

What is the time scale for cAMP-dependent pathway cascades that start at the level of ligand binding to a G-protein receptor and finish at the level of gene transcription regulation?

For example, when corticotropin releasing hormone binds to CRH receptor 1, a cAMP-dependent pathway cascade is initiated, which ultimately leads to an upregulation in the transcription of proopiomelanocortin (POMC) mRNA.

I recognize that this is a very broad question, that is likely highly case dependent (i.e. different from receptor-ligand pair to receptor-ligand pair). Nonetheless, are we looking at several hundred milliseconds? Several seconds? Several minutes?

In the case of CRH, how quickly does CRH-CRH receptor 1 binding lead to the upregulated transcription of POMC mRNA?

If there are any good sources to read about this, I would greatly appreciate it!